# Getting extra Row containing Null Value for specific Names

Tags: sql

In my Query if CompanyName has Coamount = NULL then Final should be as of Contract amount. If CompanyName has Coamount then Final would be ContractAmount + Coamount.

I am getting all these answers but the query is also returning me rows which has NULL value in Coamount for those company name in which coamount is already present.

for eg: Row1,  why is that row coming when I am getting row 2 as my answer according to my query.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                    HBRegions.RegionName,PropertyGroups.Name AS Owner,Properties.EntityID,  Properties.Address,Vendors.CompanyName,
                    SubContractorDrawDetails.InvoiceUploadDate,SubContractorDrawDetails.InvoiceAmount,SubContractorDrawDetails.PaymentDate,
                     LienWaivers.FinalLienWaiverRcvdDate,SubContractorDrawDetails.PaymentAmount, subcontractors.ContractAmount,cc.Coamount ,
                     (subcontractors.ContractAmount + cc.Coamount ) AS ActualContractAmount,

                     case when cc.Coamount is null then SubContractors.ContractAmount
                     when CC.Coamount is not null then (subcontractors.ContractAmount + cc.Coamount ) end as Final

FROM         Users inner JOIN
                      Vendors ON Users.UserId = Vendors.UserID inner JOIN
                      LienWaivers ON Users.UserId = LienWaivers.UserID inner JOIN
                      Constructions ON LienWaivers.ConstructionID = Constructions.ConstructionId inner JOIN
                      Properties ON Constructions.HBId = Properties.HBId inner  JOIN
                      ChangeOrderDetails ON Constructions.ConstructionId = ChangeOrderDetails.ConstructionId left JOIN
                      ChangeOrderLineItems ON Users.UserId = ChangeOrderLineItems.SubContractorId AND 
                      ChangeOrderDetails.ChangeOrderId = ChangeOrderLineItems.ChangeOrderId

                      left join
                      (select  sum(ChangeOrderDetails.ChangeOrderApprovedAmountContractor) as Coamount, ChangeOrderLineItems.SubContractorId,Constructions.ConstructionId
                      from ChangeOrderDetails  inner join ChangeOrderLineItems
                      on ChangeOrderDetails.ChangeOrderId = ChangeOrderLineItems.ChangeOrderId 
                      inner join Users on ChangeOrderLineItems.SubContractorId = Users.UserId 
                      left join Constructions on Constructions.ConstructionId = ChangeOrderDetails.ConstructionId 
                     -- left join  Properties on Properties.HBId = Constructions.HBId 
                    where ChangeOrderDetails.ChangeOrderApprovedAmountContractor is not null
                      group by ChangeOrderLineItems.SubContractorId,Constructions.ConstructionId
                      ) AS cc on cc.SubContractorId = ChangeOrderLineItems.SubContractorId and cc.ConstructionId = Constructions.ConstructionId
                    inner join   HBRegions ON Properties.RegionId = HBRegions.RegionID inner JOIN
                      PropertyGroups ON Properties.PropertyGroup = PropertyGroups.PropertyGroupId
                    inner join  SubContractors ON Users.UserId = SubContractors.UserID AND Properties.HBId = SubContractors.HBId 
                    inner join SubContractorDrawDetails ON SubContractors.SubContractorId = SubContractorDrawDetails.SubContractorId

WHERE (Properties.Address = '470 ROYCROFT BLVD BUFFALO NY 14225')[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Its not working. I am sorry If I was not not expressive.

Comment: Its not working. I am sorry If I was not not expressive. My question is even if Coamount has value, I am getting a duplicate row with Null value in it. So there are two rows, 1. which has coamount 2. coamount with Null value . I want to get rid of the second row which has null value